# Should I suggest a new question title?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, title

I've just submitted a long answer to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370089/recover-password-user) and, in the interest of making the whole question more useful, edited the question body for spelling and grammar.

However, I was unsure about the etiquette of editing a question title like this; "recover password- user" is not a question and is badly formatted, but does it warrant editing?  What is the etiquette surrounding this issue?

Comment: Its help text is "what's your programming question? be specific". So, like Chris already answered: yes please!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The title should be at the very least meaningful, so yes go ahead and edit it.